# Display pathfinding outcome on console

Tags: java, tree, path-finding, a-star

I have an implementation of an [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) path finding algorithm, which is a generalisation of [Dijkstra's Algorithm for the shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). The result is a graph consisting of nodes, each node has 0 to 8 neighbours.

There are some situations where a path cannot be found, when it theoretical should be possible. When this happens this means debugging, which can be difficult with large unstructured data. Therefore I would like to store the output in a tree like structure. The question that should be answered by that tree is: *At which node the result goes down the drain?*

I think a visual representation of the state is more helpful in answering that question, than a list of entries of nodes that are added to be inspected.

1. How to best display the structure of the investigated path? As this is a graph with commonly more than two neighbours the display for binary trees does not work.
2. What is the best data structure used to suite this need?

The output should be on the console. However if there are solutions that provide a graphical display that would also be great.

One possible output I can image is something like this:

```
source
|                   \         \
neigbour0            neigbour1 neigbour2
|        \           |
neigbiur0 neighbour1 neighbour0 ...
```

The number of indents would be based on the depth and the preceding elements on the same level. Each neigbour is actually displayed as int coordinates of max 1000, so the the neighbour label would be at max 9 characters long.

Comment: Is the algorithm being applied to 2D mazes or similar? Or does it need to work for higher dimensions?

Comment: Are nodes connected only to adjacent nodes (i.e. a hexagonal grid)? Then maybe display it that way and use coloring of nodes to represent their state in the algorithm.

Comment: @Felk: Yes the field of application is 2D with every node having a maximum of 8 possible neighbours (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW). For the starting and end point there are never 8 neighbours and for each node in the graph there are then only 7 possibilities of unexplored neighbours, as the 8th is the node through which the current node is reached.